# Is there any way I can restore a DB2 backup file onto IBM DashDB?

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud, dashdb

I am trying to restore a DB2 backup file into my BlueMix DashDB service. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Do you use the free shared version of dashDB or are you on a dedicated instance? The answer depends on that information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot restore your DB2 backup image into dashDB for several reasons.

In an entry-level, shared dashDB instance you only have access to one schema in a physical database shared by others.

Even if you have a dedicated instance, you need 1) access to the database local disk to upload the image and 2) sufficient privileges (at least SYSMAINT authority) to perform the restore. I doubt either will be available to you.

What you can do is run `db2look` and `db2move` locally to extract your database DDL statements and data respectively. You can then run the extracted DDL script against dashDB provided you replace the original schema name(s) with the one available to you in dashDB and, after creating the tables, load your data into them.

Comment: dashDB is also available as dedicated, private instance. I am not sure about the admin interface and would contact support (if you have a dedicated version of dashDB).