# Creating BUFFERPOOL in Bluemix dashDB

Tags: ibm-cloud, dashdb

I have an application that makes a connection to the dashDB, but prior to the application creating tables the application needs to create an 8K BUFFERPOOL.  This fails with a permission error indicating the BUFFERPOOL cannot be created.

> Error: SQL Error: SQLCODE=-552, SQLSTATE=42502,
>   SQLERRMC=DASH108016;CREATE BUFFERPOOL, DRIVER=3.50.152

Does dashDB allow the creation of bufferpools dependent on the type of Bluemix account being used?

Comment: See if this answers your question too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36087962/is-there-any-way-i-can-restore-a-db2-backup-file-onto-ibm-dashdb/36088152#36088152. Why do you need an 8K bufferpool? I'm sure they have a 32K bufferpool created for you, which should cover the 8K requirements.

Comment: dashDB is the product/service name, but there are different plans with different setups and features available. Which one are you using?

Comment: Thank you guys for responding.  I talked with IBM Bluemix team and was informed there are indeed different features and setups depending on the Bluemix account.  I will need to upgrade to enterprise instance with blueadmin access and above.